# Should I rename my question to make it more searchable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400557/shell-script-thinks-directory-does-not-exist-when-running-cd) earlier today and the author of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41400672/5937428) also included some help with another issue that was not part of the original question. Since the answer is still on-topic, providing the answer to the question, there is no reason to get rid of it (not that I would want to anyway). 15 minutes before the edit I would have been happy to find this extra answer under another question, so it is helpful information.

My question is, should I edit the title and/or content of the question to make the extra part of the answer easier to find/search, as it is not currently an intuitive extension of my original issue?

Comment: You mean the "Also, don't use .." part? To me, it seems 'free advice' and rather unrelated to your question. It's not uncommon to find such nuggets of additional tips & hints on SO. I think editing a (second!) question into your existing one would be quite confusing.

Comment: @RadLexus - Yeah, that part.While not uncommon to stumble across them, would it not be useful to make them easier for others to find than? Now that I think about it, perhaps this is something better used as a resource to add to documentation.

Comment: Remember that the contents of answers are "searchable", too, so something doesn't need to be in the question in order for it to be findable.